# Match column1 from table1 with column1 in table2 and return * records from table2 which are matched with column1 of table1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have tried this:

```
select *
from table2
where exists (
    select *
    from table1
    where table2.column1 = table1.column1
)
```

Output: It returns all table headers of the columns from table2 but is not returning any records.

Observation: When I am trying to match inter valued columns it is returning records. But its not working while matching character valued columns

Note: column1 from table1 and table2 both are having character values.

```
select [Data Name]
from [DynamicDataTable]
where exists (
    select *
    from University_Temp
    where DynamicDataTable.autocode = University_Temp.autocode
)
```

Output of above query

```
[Data Name]
Title  
First Name  
Geebee Centre  
Country of Permanent Residence  
SSC Institute/College
```

The above query is returning records of matching autocodes which are of data type interger.

Comment: Could you try running this code `select * from table2, table1 where table2.column1=table1.column1;`? Does it output any record?

Comment: Could you also post the code you mentioned it works in your question (match inter valued columns)?

Comment: @user696969 Please stop using this ancient join style. It has been deprecated ages ago

Comment: @GuidoG I want to use it for verifying if there are records in the database that satisfy the condition. There are more efficient ways to get similar result but this seems to be the simplest approach

Comment: @user696969 How is using a deprecated join style the simplest approach ? Don't understand me wrong, I think you are right with your idea of using a join. But why use this old ancient and deprecated join style ?

Comment: Please edit your question and put any relevant information in the question, not in comments. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67135229/edit)

Comment: Posting a query that works cannot help us help you with the query that does not works. Post sample data and post the result you want.

Comment: We need to see the data where the query fails. Pleas post sample data

Answer (score 0):

So you want to see all rows in `table2` where `Column1` matches with `Column1` from `table1` ?
If I understand you right this is just a simple join

```
select t2.*
from   table2 t2
  inner join table1 t1 on t2.Column1 = t1.Column1
```

If this is not what you want, than please edit your question and explain in more detail what you need

Comment: Maybe he wants to get matched records of second table so left join can be used

Comment: same results with this query, problem is that its working fine with integer data type columns, not with nvarchar data type columns, if i am matching columns like name its not working, eg., t2.col1(which is of data type nvarchar)=t1.col1(nvarchar data type)

Comment: are both columns in both tables the same datatype ? Please show us some sample data where this query does not works

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao Possible yes, that is why I put in my answer to explain in more detail what he wants

Comment: We need to see the data where the query fails. Pleas post sample data